# Using Ruby on Cygwin in Vista

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby programming. I have installed cygwin on vista. I am in the learners stage. I want to know how to interpret simple ruby commands in cygwin. For example:

```
def palindrome?(string)
string = string.downcase.gsub(/\W/,'')
string == string.reverse
end
```

I have look upon various methods of using cygwin for ruby but they all are targeted towards making of a rails application. I am just looking for a simple ruby interpreter using cygwin or any other tool.

Currently I am using online interpreter at [Codeacademy Labs](http://labs.codecademy.com/)

Comment: is there a reason you put ruby via cygwin?

Comment: I applaud your desire to use Ruby via Cygwin but jjlin's comment below and even the native command prompt window installed with Ruby on Windows using the RubyInstaller are better; especially with Vista. http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: @ScottJShea Ok... I will give it a try!! I thought cygwin is like terminal on Macs and that is the reason of using Cygwin!

Comment: @Panagiotis Yes!! I want a terminal on Mac like experience on Vista!!

Comment: @SilentKiller theoretically it is but at that point you are using Ruby inside a command interpreter, inside another command interpreter on top of a third command interpreter. At least the RubyInstaller cuts out one of the mess. And the IRB helps isolate it even more but makes it harder to do longer scripts.

Comment: Well yes cygwin is **emulating** a terminal, sortof, but ruby - interactively is not like compiling a c program on the terminal. If you want to check if ruby script is running use the irb or run it by ruby <filename>.rb. Or use an IDE with debugging capabilities.

Comment: @ScottJShea Ok I got it. So is there any simple alternative for doing longer scripts?

Comment: @SilentKiller Just write them out in a text editor (I use Notepad++), save them as `name.rb` (whatever name you want) and then from the command prompt do `ruby -w name.rb`. The `-w` gives you warnings along with the script output so if you do not want them just omit the `-w`

Comment: @ScottJShea wow!! That is so cool!! I was not knowing that!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `irb` ([Interactive Ruby Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell)). This comes with the stock Ruby distribution.

Comment: I don;t know how to use irb!! I think its too complicated!! I want something straight forward like terminal where I could directly interpret the code!

Comment: @SilentKiller irb is not complicated at all. However, this might be even less threatening http://tryruby.org/

Comment: Once you use the Ruby command window (Windows DOS Window with Ruby ENV vars) you will see how the IRB simplifies things. On the command prompt you might do `ruby -e 'puts "Hello World"` while in IRB it would be just `puts "Hello World".

Comment: @Ingenu thanks! I was trying to remember that link (so easy too...).